# Why is SQL Server seperate from the roles in Windows Server 2008 Server Manager?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, database

I have an instance of Windows Server 2008 running on my machine. Within the OS there is a useful application called Server Manager, where I can manage several roles for my machine (such as web server, file server, application server, etc). However, the option for database server (through MS SQL Server) does not exist as a role.

Instead, I have to have a separate installation of SQL Server to associate my machine with this role. What are the reasons for having the SQL Server as a stand-alone application as oppose to a built-in role?

Comment: Kindly explain downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because SQL Server is an add-on product that has to be purchased/licensed, as opposed to an optional feature built-in to the OS, as IIS is.

The same situation holds true for anything from MS that isn't bundled with the OS, like Exchange, BizTalk, SharePoint, etc.

Comment: Right, but logically doesn't SQL Server fall within the same category of 'Role' such as IIS, Active Directory and what not? I guess you are saying its a marketing technique, as oppose to a technical reason.

Comment: No, absolutely not. You don't have to pay extra for IIS, AD, etc. *That's the difference.* The "roles" are what's *included* with the windows license you already paid for. Things like SQL *cost more money* and are *separate.*